# global implicit function theorem and bi-Lipschitz map

Tags: real-analysis

Take a Lipschitz function $g: \mathbf{R}^2\to \mathbf{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{2}\le \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\le 2,$ a.e. in $\mathbf{R}^2$ and $|\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}|\le \frac{1}{100}$, a.e. in $\mathbf{R}^2$. Then can we conclude that the map $(x, y)\to (g(x, y), y)$ from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathbf{R}^2$ is bi-Lipschitz?

For $g$ being $C^1$ (continuously differentiable functions), this is true and is quite easy to see. But now we only have the information for the derivative "almost everywhere", might it be possible that we lose the global structure?

Comment: This seems more suitable for math stack exchange. What is the research angle of this question?

Comment: Thanks, Misha, I will try there.@Misha